# How can I prompt to add to the uses clause in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ide

Just upgraded from Delphi XE to Tokyo, and was hoping for some updated IDE features.

One nice to have feature would be automatically providing options to add a unit to the uses clause. For example, if you reference something in code that isn't in a uses, it would be nice if the IDE prompted you to add the related unit(s).

For example, keeping it simple, in IntelliJ, you might declare a Button, but not yet have added the associated Library to the Import clause.

[image: For Example IntelliJ/Android Studio]

When this happens, the offending line is highlighted (just like in Delphi), but the IDE will let you add the necessary library with an Alt-Enter.  If there are multiple libraries (it knows about it) it will prompt you for the one you want.

Can I do something like this in Delphi's Tokyo version?

Comment: I guess the problem is that the IDE does not really know anything about code that is not in the `uses`. There is no offline database the IDE could use to find such an identifier and the unit it is in. I assume someone could generate such a database and write a nice expert for it, but I don't know of any yet.

Comment: @Rudy, sure a library of known types would be nice, these could be gleaned from the units available in the library path.  This is probably how intelliJ does it.  For other types, eg, locally defined ones these could be gleaned from the project code/available paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delphi 2007 and later versions support this for most types that it knows about (in the search or library path). (It may have been available in D2005/2006; I don't have them installed anywhere now to check. I know it was not in Delphi 7.)

Put in the type, and use the Refactor menu (Refactor->Find Unit) or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Here's an example:

[image: ![Find unit dialog]

It's not 100% effective, but it's a vast improvement over the old way.

(And yes, I know about `TArray<string>`, before someone chimes in. I just grabbed a quick type that I knew wouldn't be in the default VCL form uses clause for an example.)

Comment: Does it also find identifiers that are not in a unit in the uses clause? I just tried with a console app, and I couldn't find TButton. I could find identifiers that were in the uses clause. But perhaps I didn't do things right? The VCL is in the library path, AFAIK.

Comment: @Rudy: I don't know exactly what it will or won't search. It found `System.Types` in the example I used, which is not in the `uses` clause. All I have is [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Find_Unit) and a blog post somewhere (can't recall offhand where, but I'll try to find it).

Comment: @Rudy: Actually, [Berlin docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Finding_Units_(Delphi)) have a somewhat better description, but it's still not highly informative about where it will look.

Comment: AFAIK, it only looks in units (directly?) used in the current project. I tried in a DUnit project, and it still did not find TButton, although I am sure the project has buttons.

Comment: @Rudy: Clearly not, as `System.Types` is **not** used in the example I posted (see the image, which very intentionally included the `uses` clause to demonstrate that fact - you can see both the `interface` and `implementation` sections, and there's no `System.Types` in either of them), and my final paragraph indicates why I chose `TStringDynArray` as the type (because I knew `System.Types` was not in the default units).

Comment: Hmmm... the project has a toolbar and it could indeed find TToolBar in Vcl.ComCtrls. System.Types is probably used indirectly, i.e. by one of the other units in the project.

Comment: @Rudy: I can't explain what the functionality does. The poster asked if something existed in the IDE, and I pointed out that it did. How it works (or how well) is something I can't really address. I can just say it's there.

Comment: Hasn't that functionality been part oft the IDE since, like forever? It certainly is available in Delphi 2007 (And wasn't there in Delphi 7.)

Comment: @dummzeuch: Yeah, it's been around a while. I just couldn't say for certain when it was added, as I only have Seattle and up on this machine. I was going to check D2007 and one of the XE versions when I go to work on Monday and edit then.